# Can't stop the cycle

Tags: python

I'm trying to find the winner of the runoff voting.

In the example below there are four voters and three candidates, to become winner the candidate should collect more then 50% of the votes. If nobody does - i should remove the candidates who collected the least votes and took new leaders of the voters. For example, after thee first round i remove "dem" from first voter and "rep" from second, and take their second places = "Ind" and "Ind". In this case I have 4 "ind" and it is elections winner. And the code below works, until every voter has different candidates. Let's say, if three voters put three candidates on the first place - there Winner should be None. But instead I got infinite loop. What is the problem with my code?

```
def runoff(voters):

row = []
exclude = []
vote = voters
winner = False
for i in vote:
    row.append(i[0])
print("NEW ROW: ", row)
while not winner:
    for i in row:
        if row.count(i) >= len(row) // 2+1:
            winner = i
            print("Winner: ", winner)
            break
        if row.count(i) == 1:
            exclude.append(i)
    print("To exclude: ", exclude)
    for i in vote:
        if not i:
            winner = None
        else:
            for m in exclude:
                i.remove(m)
                row = []
                exclude = []
                row.append(i[0])
    print("New vote: ", vote)


print("The winner is: ", winner)

runoff([["dem", "ind", "rep"],
              ["rep", "ind", "dem"],
              ["ind", "dem", "rep"],
              ["ind", "rep", "dem"]])
```

The output for this option is:

"The winner is:  ind"

But if i try to run the code with voters like:

```
[["a", "c", "d", "e", "b"],
["e", "b", "d", "c", "a"],
["d", "e", "c", "a", "b"],
["c", "e", "d", "b", "a"],
["b", "e", "a", "c", "d"]]
```

- it gives me:

  NEW ROW:  ['a', 'e', 'd', 'c', 'b']
  To exclude:  ['a', 'e', 'd', 'c', 'b']

and then:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

So it removes all the symbols from array but then tries to add some symbols from array, which is already empty, to row, even though I expect it to set the Winner to None and break the cycle.

Comment: Did you try to check what is happening in the code, when the loop happens? For example, if you add a pause every time through the loop and `print` the variable values, can you see a pattern emerging? I see there are already what look like some test outputs like `print("To exclude: ", exclude)`. **What results did you get** from those? Based on those outputs, what is your understanding of what is happening?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow, can you please be more specific about the current output and the desired output? If you have an error message post it here in full. Also you can try `print(locals())` to print all variable names and their values to help with debugging

Comment: Good I see that you are making progress in your debugging, now ask yourself WHY could it be that it removes all the symbols from array but the tries to add some symbols from array to row, even though I expect it to set the Winner to None and break the cycle. What are some variables that you would be interested in seeing their values in the loop to check if the error is with them? Choose them and also print their values

Comment: You can also use `print(locals())` to print all locals variables with their name

Comment: Basically any instant-runoff voting system is going to have edge cases like this. Your specific problem is due to not removing emptied ballots from your `vote`/`voters` list (side-note: Why alias to `vote`? Just use `voters` the whole time!), so you try to select the next preference from voter(s) who have no preferences that have not been eliminated. You need to completely remove eliminated ballots, and you need to add end conditions that handle ties, either due to *all* ballots being eliminated, or due to all remaining ballots splitting *exactly* evenly between all contenders.